# Check overwrite in File Save dialog in WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I need to check if the same file exists when I try to save a file in File Save Dialog. İf it does,
it shouldnt allow me to do it and force me to change the name. How can I do this in WxPython?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my save code:

```
        #Dosya tipi filtreleri
        wildcard = "BENGI files (*.bengi)|*.bengi|"    \
       "SQLITE file (*.sdb)|*.sdb|"        \
       "All files (*.*)|*.*"

        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Save file as ...", defaultDir=DesktopPath, 
            defaultFile="_nokta_listesi", wildcard=wildcard, style=wx.SAVE
            )


        # Varsayılan dosya tipi filtresi
        dlg.SetFilterIndex(0)

        # Show the dialog and retrieve the user response. If it is the OK response, 
        # process the data.
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()

            # Create a database in disk
            con=apsw.Connection(path)

            # Copy from memory to disk
            with con.backup("main", self.conn2, "main") as backup:
                backup.step() # copy whole database in one go

            con.close(True) 
        dlg.Destroy()
```

Comment: either close the question or add an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: What does "Varsayılan dosya tipi filtresi" mean?

Comment: It means "oh bro big time"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I added "wx.OVERWRITE_PROMPT" flag to the style.